# Populate a Javascript Grid via Flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I can't get this to work. I generate several JSON files with Flask-Restless, e.g.

```
{
  "num_results": 6,
  "objects": [
    {
      "name": "Production"
    },
    {
      "name": "Warehouse X"
    },
    {
      "name": "Warehouse Y"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sale"
    },
    {
      "name": "Warehouse Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "Transport"
    }
  ],
  "page": 1,
  "total_pages": 1
}
```

Which are accessed via REST-Interface (GET on /api/account)

I try to use this data to populate a JS-library, namely [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com/), but it doesn't seem to be able to parse the data. My loadData function looks like this:

```
loadData: function(filter) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/account",
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            },
```

Which results in a "Not Found" message. If I try this or similar approaches in the JS console I get an Object with a .responseJSON property, which I can't seem to access in the script itself. How do I translate the resulting Object in a JSON readable by jsGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Is your flask server running on a different port? You need to include the entire url for that.

For instance if you are running your flask server on port 5000 you would ask for your endpoint at url: "http://" + location.hostname + ":5000/api/account"

If it is running on the same port, "http://" + location.hostname + "/api/account"